# JQuery activates a radiobutton

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I created a multi-button as follows:

```
<div class="form-inline graph-dashboard">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"> 
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input id="B1" type="radio"> Tweet count
        </label> 
        <label class="btn btn-default"> 
            <input id="B2" type="radio"> # Followers
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I am trying to make `#B1` toggled on startup (i.e., clicked).

**What I obtain when the page is loaded:**

[image]

**What I would like to obtain when the page is loaded:**

[image]

**Tried (and not working) solutions:**

- `$('#B1').addClass("active");`
- `$('#B1').prop("checked", true);`
- `$('#B1').button("toggle");`
- `$('#B1').parent("label").addClass("active");`

How can I fix the problem? Solutions that modify the HTML code are accepted too, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `checked` property:

```
<input id="B1" type="radio" checked>
```

Or

```
$("#B1").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Tried and does not fix the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Try adding "active" to the label: `$("#B1").parent("label").addClass("active");` @Eleanore

Comment: Im not sure what you're trying to achieve... setting the `checked` property will have the radio checked - inspect the element when it has the desired style and find what classes need to be added.

Comment: I just want to pre-toggle the button... I'll add a figure.